# Fundamental thoerem of calculus for Stochastic integrals?

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, differential

I'm trying to understand how to convert an Ito process from integral form:

[image]

to differential form

[image]

First 2 terms are straightfoward
dX = X_t - X_0 and fundamental theorem is applied to 1st integral to get udt. However, what I'm unsure is how to get the last integral term? Specifically, why is

[image]

Comment: It is preferred that you use MathJax to render equations directly instead of embedding images in your post. Here is a link to a tutorial for using MathJax on this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also, I do not think it would be formally correct to say that $$\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dt}\int_0^t \sigma_s\ \mathsf d W_s = \sigma_t\mathsf dW_t. $$

Comment: I second @Math1000 ‘s comment. In the literature I have read (e.g. Rogers and Williams) $\sigma dW_t$ is informal short-hand notation for the Itô integral $\int_0^t \sigma dW_s$, and nothing more.